# when I click on X button animation is not played in React and Styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I wanted to create Popup with styled components and added animation for fade in and fade out. But the problem is that when I close popup by clicking on X button the animation is not played. Here is my code:

> import React, { useRef, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';
> import styled, {keyframes} from 'styled-components'; import { MdClose
> as PopupClose } from 'react-icons/md';
>
> const fadeIn = keyframes`   from {
> opacity: 0;   }
>
> to {
> opacity: 1;   } `;
>
> const fadeOut = keyframes`   from {
> opacity: 0;   }
>
> to {
> opacity: 1;   } `;
>
> const Background = styled.div<{ref: any, showPopup: boolean}>  `top: 0;   bottom: 0;   left: 0;   right: 0;   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);   position: fixed;   display: flex;   justify-content: center;   align-items: center;   transition: all .3s;   animation:${props => props.showPopup ? fadeIn : fadeOut} .3s;`;
>
> const PopupWrapper = styled.div<{noRoundCorners?: boolean}>  `width: 600px;   background: #fff;   position: relative;   z-index: 10;   border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;   box-sizing: border-box;   box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px rgba(67, 67, 67, 0.1);   border-radius:${({noRoundCorners})=> noRoundCorners ? '1px' : '40px'};   transition: all .2s;`;
>
> const PopupContentWrapper = styled.div<{noRoundCorners?: boolean}>`
> height: 650px;   overflow-y: auto;
>
> ::-webkit-scrollbar {
> width: 10px;   }
>
> ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
> margin-bottom: ${({noRoundCorners})=> noRoundCorners ? '1px' : '35px'};
> background-color: transparent;   }
>
> ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
> background-color: #3AA4A4;
> border-radius: 20px;
> border: 3px solid transparent;
> background-clip: content-box;   } `
>
> const PopupContent = styled.div  `height: 1000px;   padding-left: 30px;   padding-right: 30px;`;
>
> const PopupHeader = styled.div  `display: flex;`;
>
> const Header = styled.p`font-family: Open Sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; line-height: 24px; margin-left: 30px;`;
>
> const ClosePopupButton = styled(PopupClose)  `cursor: pointer;   position: absolute;   top: 20px;   right: 20px;   width: 32px;   height: 32px;   padding: 0;   z-index: 10;   transition: all .2s;`;
>
> type PopupProps = {
> showPopup: boolean;
> noRoundCorners?: boolean;
> header: string;
> setShowPopup: Dispatch<SetStateAction>;
> children?: React.ReactNode; }
>
> export const Popup = ({ showPopup, noRoundCorners, children, header,
> setShowPopup }: PopupProps) => {   const PopupRef = useRef();
>
> const closePopup = (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
> if (PopupRef.current === e.target) {
> setShowPopup(false);
> }   };
>
> return (
> <>
> {showPopup ? (
>
>
>
> {header}
> <ClosePopupButton
> aria-label='Close Popup'
> onClick={() => setShowPopup((prev:boolean) => !prev)}
> />
>
>
>
> {children}
>
>
>
>
> ) : null}
> </>   ); };

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you component is get unmounted as soon as you press the close button.

```
  const closePopup = (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
 if (PopupRef.current === e.target) {
   setShowPopup(false);
 }   };
```

You cna put a timeout to see the closing animation.

```
    const closePopup = (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    if (PopupRef.current === e.target) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            setShowPopup(false);
        }, 300);
    }
};
```